# Malformed JSON running Jest in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs

I'm trying to setup jest configuration for IntelliJ but I'm getting this error in the IDE `Failed to parse Jest config jest.config.js: malformed JSON`:
[image]

However, the tests work in the console:

```
➜  project-web git:(master) ✗ jest --config jest.config.js src/client/components
 PASS  src/client/components/FormInput/index.test.tsx
 PASS  src/client/components/Card/index.test.tsx
 PASS  src/client/components/Button/indext.test.tsx
 PASS  src/client/components/StepsBar/components/Step/Step.test.jsx
 FAIL  src/client/components/Help/index.test.tsx
```

Whith this IDE configuration:
[image: IDE configuration]

And `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
  ["moduleNameMapper"]: {
    // These take care of webpack's alias
    ["^Redux(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/redux$1",
    ["^Static(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/static$1",
    ["^Components(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/components$1",
    ["^Hoc(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/hoc$1",
    ["^Services(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/services$1",
    ["^Constants(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/constants$1",
    ["^Scenes(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/scenes$1",
    ["^Types(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/types",
    ["^Helpers(.*)"]: "<rootDir>/src/client/helpers$1",

    // These take care of imports of non-js assets (which are allowed by
    // webpack, but not by Babel). Will import the object specified in the
    // matching mock file instead of the asset. The object keys act as regex.
    ["\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$"]: "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    ["\\.(css|less)$"]: "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    // NOTE: in the regexs above, "\\." means "a literal period" because the two
    // slashes collapse into one.
  },
  // Test files to exclude. Note that node_modules are excluded by default, but
  // because we're overwriting the default array, they must be added again.
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/src/build/", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],

  // Transform functions. Any file matching the following regexs will be
  // transpiled **synchronously** with the specified function.
  transform: {
    ["^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$"]: "<rootDir>/src/build/test/transformer.js"
  },
  testMatch: [
    "**/*.test.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)"
  ],
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/src/client/", "<rootDir>/src/static/"],
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/test/jestSetup.js"],
  snapshotSerializers: ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
}
```

If I don't set a configuration file in the configuration of the IDE it runs the test with the default configuration and not my `jest.config.js` file.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having this issue too. I can the tests to run in webstorm if i make that jest.config.js pure JSON (remove ```module.exports =``` ), but then i can't run from the terminal

Comment: I created an issue in their platform. I'm going to keep you updated.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in IDE Intellij 2017.3

I was using 2017.2.6

Answered here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182942